# How can i run sikuli 1.1.0 from command line as administrator?

Tags: command-line, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I understand that when you right click on `runsikuliX.cmd` and select "Run as administrator", will enable you Sikuli scripts to run smoothly.  Please advise on how can I can implement this via command line. I tried executing the following command but still click and find actions were not triggered:

```
runas /env /user:<localhost>\Administrator runsikuliX.cmd -r sikuli script
```

I'm using Windows 8 64 bit, java 1.7.0_45.

Comment: I am not convinced that this is what's causing your problem. Sikuli should work just fine when running it as a regular user. What is your problem exactly? Does Sikuli perform any of the actions or nothing at all?

Comment: I have a similar scenario with https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/251336, wherein other actions were not performed, but if I run as Admin, it can detect even commands such as keydown and keyup.  But the difference with the mentioned scenario is that I need to run the sikuli command via command line.

Answer (score 0):

For AutoIT we use command "start"

start /env /user:\Administrator runsikuliX.cmd -r sikuli script